# ElasticSearch - Match all terms in any order

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to write an elasticsearch (v5.1) query to check whether all tokens in a field match **all tokens in a search term**, but in **any order**.

For example the field could be:

```
full_name: 'Will Smith'
```

And the search terms `Will Smith` or `Smith Will` would match. However searching `Will` or `Smith` would not match.

I've tried match queries with the `and` operator and phrase queries with `slop`, but these all ensured that the terms search were all in the field, not that all terms in the field were in the search.

I could index with a new field like `reversed_name` but was wondering if there was a query option I was missing somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

You should take a look at the bool query with "minimum_should_match" parameter. It would look something like this in your case:

```
 {   
    "query":{
        "bool" : {
            "should" : [
               {"term" : { "name" : "Will" }},
               {"term" : { "name" : "Smith" }}
             ],
             "minimum_should_match" : 2
          }
       }
    }
}
```

This would match "Will Smith" and "Smith Will". If you would like to search only Will or Smith then you would need to change it to this:

```
 {   
    "query":{
        "bool" : {
            "should" : [
               {"term" : { "name" : "Will" }}
             ],
             "minimum_should_match" : 1
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Only "Will" will be matched this time. (exact match)

Comment: If its about matching all terms, then instead of specifying "minimum_should_match" with `should`, I would suggest to go with 'must' clause. This will make query more easy and readable.

Comment: what if the document looked like this: "Will Smith Michael" ? Then minimum_should_match will not work?